# Creating a Go Lambda function in AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I'm looking for information on how to create a lambda function written in Go in Cloud9. I can see in the Cloud9 doc how to do it for node.js and python based on templates, but nothing on Go or Java. Does anyone has any pointer how to create one from scratch?

Thank you,

Vin

Comment: Using SAM directly in the Cloud9 env solved my issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the date of this reply, the **Lambda** section of the **AWS Resources** window in the AWS Cloud9 IDE works with AWS Lambda functions written in Node.js and Python only.

Paul (AWS Cloud9 Documentation)